# Get all playlist ids from channel id - youtube api v3

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I am currently learning the use of the `youtube api`. I want to retrieve all `playlists id` from a `channel id`. I read through the documentation and saw that I can use `youtube.channels.list` for such task. I did basic testing on the [api_page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list). Still, I am not able to figure what `params` to use to get the `playlist id`. How can I retrieve all `playlist ids` from a given `channel id`?

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id&id=UCF0pVplsI8R5kcAqgtoRqoA&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A simple way :

With the [YouTube API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/) with the ressource [playlists.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list)

Use this parameters to get the playlists ID of a channel :

```
part: 'snippet'
channelId: 'UCBkNpeyvBO2TdPGVC_PsPUA'
```

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet&channelId=UCBkNpeyvBO2TdPGVC_PsPUA&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

The  output :

```
 "items": [
  {

   "kind": "youtube#playlist",
   "etag": "\"PSjn-HSKiX6orvNhGZvglLI2lvk/K21sgPQuMRCjhSMBjm3v3n5tl1o\"",
   "id": "PL2qcutlDmS0CnyV8Jcbl2d7yFxd2iGg67",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2014-07-08T03:13:37.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCBkNpeyvBO2TdPGVC_PsPUA",
    "title": "These Things Happen Series",
    "description": "",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/93mgU_VXZrA/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/93mgU_VXZrA/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/93mgU_VXZrA/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     },
     "standard": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/93mgU_VXZrA/sddefault.jpg",
      "width": 640,
      "height": 480
     },
     "maxres": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/93mgU_VXZrA/maxresdefault.jpg",
      "width": 1280,
      "height": 720
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "GEazyTV"
   }
  },
  {

   "kind": "youtube#playlist",
   "etag": "\"PSjn-HSKiX6orvNhGZvglLI2lvk/5ifuvTYKbyV6DUPqbTa2bnO2jWY\"",
   "id": "PL2qcutlDmS0B0jwHOQYzgRhJpnxDwPBHc",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2014-06-05T07:36:58.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCBkNpeyvBO2TdPGVC_PsPUA",
    "title": "B-Sides",
    "description": "",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/f7Ua9wKvVtI/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/f7Ua9wKvVtI/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/f7Ua9wKvVtI/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     },
     "standard": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/f7Ua9wKvVtI/sddefault.jpg",
      "width": 640,
      "height": 480
     },
     "maxres": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/f7Ua9wKvVtI/maxresdefault.jpg",
      "width": 1280,
      "height": 720
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "GEazyTV"
   }
  },
...
```

This is a sample example with a random channel.

If you don't know how to get the **channelID** of a channel use ressource [channels.list:](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list)

With this parameters to get the video ID of a playlist :

```
part: 'id'
forUsername: 'channel_name'
```

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id&forUsername=GEazyTV&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

```
 "items": [
  {

   "kind": "youtube#channel",
   "etag": "\"PSjn-HSKiX6orvNhGZvglLI2lvk/vIwM6ev74Om0AOupX26jJoEDELU\"",
   "id": "UCBkNpeyvBO2TdPGVC_PsPUA"
  }
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to work with the php client. Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26831919/get-all-playlist-ids-from-channel-id-youtube-api-v3

Comment: YT channels are infuriating when you want to get their videos over the API. Your request URL seems to work for the example you gave, but not, say, for the channel `UCdKAVgh1r5u_Vjw70PdrgjA`. Any idea why?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure how I came across this solution, but I've found that if you follow these steps then you can retrieve the playlistID to use:

1. Create an API Key using the Google API Console.
2. Use
   `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&key=[KEY FROM GOOGLE API CONSOLE]&id=[CHANNEL ID]`
   where you are replacing everything, including the brackets, with the corresponding info (I find channel ids are easy to come by since they are normally in the URL. The PlaylistID is the one that tends to be difficult).
3. The resulting feed from the URL in step 2 should contain an `uploads` object, containing the playlistID which is used in the URL in step 4.
4. Use
   `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=[PLAYLIST ID RETRIEVED IN STEP 3 HERE]&key=[KEY FROM GOOGLE API CONSOLE]`

The link from step 4 is what should end up being used in the app.

This works for me every time, and I integrate the YouTube v3 API in many apps. I completely agree with @Utkanos' [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26831919/get-all-playlist-ids-from-channel-id-youtube-api-v3/32417961#comment51542645_26833637) that while @mpgn's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26833637/3512867) works sometimes, it certainly doesn't work for all channels.

Comment: Are the channelId and the uploads the same ID?

Answer (score -2):

Youtube Api v3 Channel Playlist video max 50

This url format work

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=[]&key=[]&maxResults=50