# How does youtube looks for playlists with video ID?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

Is there any way to get all (my) playlists with my videoID?

On this page: https://www.youtube.com/edit?video_id=ID There is option "Add to playlist(s)", and list of playlists with checkboxes that checked if video already in playlists. How does youtube looks for playlists with video ID? I cant believe that in this, YoutubeAPI way:

1. Get all playlists IDs,
2. For every playlist get all videos,
3. Look for videoID in search result.

Because I have about 7000 videos in about 100 playlists. And there is parameter maxResult that no more than 50.

Comment: No, there is no way to do this. You need to give playlist-id.You can do this by providing channelid.https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26833637/4361743

Comment: So what is your main question? Do you want to get all the videos? Can you be more specific for the things that you want to achieve? thanks.

Comment: ??? you only have 100 PL's, So provided you have less than 50 vid's in each.... 101 search calls :-) . As well as YouTube probably has their own private api that is better than what they give us.