# Is there any way to get playlists count using youtube api

Tags: youtube-api, playlists

Hi friends am trying to get the exact count of number of playlists in channel using channelid using youtube api.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all playlist ids from channel id - youtube api v3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26831919/get-all-playlist-ids-from-channel-id-youtube-api-v3)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible by using the [Youtube V3 API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/) and the [playlist.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list) together with a channel id.

[Get all playlist ids from channel id - youtube api v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26831919/get-all-playlist-ids-from-channel-id-youtube-api-v3) shows how to get the playlist id's from the API.

Request sent through the API explorer:

```
part: snippet
channelId: UCBkNpeyvBO2TdPGVC_PsPUA
```

A response from  [playlist.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list)

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#playlistListResponse",
 "etag": "\"uQc-MPTsstrHkQcRXL3IWLmeNsM/GayOzLnLt1ndQVz5WvCaYWPuXUo\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 14, <--- Total number of playlists.
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#playlist",
   "etag": "\"uQc-MPTsstrHkQcRXL3IWLmeNsM/llWSSTxPt1F74kWJeadntx0oOlU\"",
   "id": "PL2qcutlDmS0BGjOf5rwjWNH6JnyFEShyb",
   "snippet": {
     // snippet information, title etc
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#playlist",
   "etag": "\"uQc-MPTsstrHkQcRXL3IWLmeNsM/D7iFaGmnjkkw29IXm-6kWaCd0a8\"",
   "id": "PL2qcutlDmS0DUCGOdr5eYDwZC_1JAReI4", 
   "snippet": {
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#playlist",
   "etag": "\"uQc-MPTsstrHkQcRXL3IWLmeNsM/0MGgZUqxHh3qkYePoEP3C9ZPamU\"",
   "id": "PL2qcutlDmS0DMB6Xv2KmlKzdOtNqMOwpv", // Count 3
   "snippet": {
        // snippet information, title etc
    }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#playlist",
   "etag": "\"uQc-MPTsstrHkQcRXL3IWLmeNsM/XMQu1lYA_nJGBD5l7JknPncuwv0\"",
   "id": "PL2qcutlDmS0CnyV8Jcbl2d7yFxd2iGg67",
   "snippet": {
        // snippet information, title etc
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

You can use the `totalResults` from `pageInfo` to get the number of playlists for that channel.

Comment: yeah but I need to click next for getting is there any way I can get the total count of playlists

Comment: What do you mean by click next?

Comment: @babu kumar , uzr has given it to you. You are looking at "resultsPerPage" which is a separate issue from your question. The "totalResults" will always give you ALL the results that there are in a given api call.